# Button inside gridview to open new window

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a button inside a gridview. I'm trying to use this button for opening a new window, but I'm getting an error message.

Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'window.open('.

ASP code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/picture.jpg" 
            Height="20px" Width="20px" 
            CommandName="OpenGroupTrend"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

VB Code

```
Protected Sub GV_SL_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If (e.CommandName = "OpenGroupTrend") Then
        Dim GroupTrendLink = "http://NewPage.aspx"
        Response.Write("<script>")
        Response.Write("window.open('" & GroupTrendLink & "','_blank')")
        Response.Write("</script>")
    End If
End Sub
```

If I use the same code outside a GridView it works okay.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not Response.Write scripts out like that.  Use the scriptmanager and register the script from there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx

Better yet, forgo posting back entirely and use an html link instead.

```
<a href="javascript: window.open('[url]','_blank')">
    <img src="Images/picture.jpg" />
<a>
```

Comment: When I use the html link as you suggested above, the new window opens okay, but the host window goes blank and shows '[object]' at the top. Also, I have to transfer values to the new window, I'm not sure how to do that whith the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work it out with scriptmanager. Thanks nickles80 for the hint. See the code below if it helps someone. I've also added the code to transfer values to the new window.

```
If (e.CommandName = "OpenGroupTrend") Then

 Dim G = e.CommandArgument.ToString
 Dim D = DateInt.Value
 Dim GroupTrendLink = "http://NewPage.aspx?D=" & D & "&G=" & G

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "key", "open('" + GroupTrendLink + "');", True)

End If
```

At the 'Newpage.aspx' I use the following code to capture the values

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim DateTrans As Integer
        DateTrans = Request.QueryString("D")
        Label1.Text = DateTrans.ToString

        Dim GroupTrans As Integer
        GroupTrans = Request.QueryString("G")
        Label2.Text = GroupTrans.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```